# Memory Exceeded in Inline.php

Tags: memory

I had created some custom attributes in my 1.9.1 install (basically for item color and size).  Well, I've noticed that upon trying to create a Configurable Product, I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 360169 bytes) in /home/(sitename)/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate/Inline.php on line 207
```

Then when I go into the inline.php file, I see this on line 207:

```
$body = preg_replace('#' . $this->_tokenRegex . '#', '$1', $body);
```

I've changed the memory in the `php.ini` file and the `.htaccess` to 512M, and the .htaccess to the actual bytes number.

I'm now out of ideas.  Any help would be awesome.

Comment: You could check what exactly this function is trying to process (log the $body variable). There could be problem with input text length.

Comment: Thanks DmitryR.  I re-checked a couple things in the code and it appears I had changed the memory amount in only one of them. So now it's allowing me to create the configurable product.  However, after I place all of the info and go to save it, I get a blank page.  Then if I go back to the Products page and click edit, I get the same blank page. :(

Answer (score 1):

create a file info.php in the magento root and write this code

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

then open it from the browser and check if the memory limit has been really changed. Sometime you need to edit the right php.ini accordingly to your php version.

Comment: Antonio, that helped alot.  Ok, so I have PHP Version 5.4.35, and the memory limit shows 32M. So, where exactly am I to change this? I thought the two places I changed them was the proper place, but I'm guessing it's not?

Comment: check in info.php which is the php.ini path

Comment: In the phpinfo output, you will see the php.ini file location. You should open it with text editor, locate the 'memory_limit = 32M', and change 32 to something bigger - 128, for example.

Comment: magento needs 512M, check also your hosting resource limits

Comment: Ok apparently the 'php.ini' file actually was 'php.ini.sample.'  So in the [file info.php] I see the memory has changed to 512M. BUT...now I get a 'There has been an error processing your request. 
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
Error log record number: 396530251831' error now.

Comment: @AntonioPedicini I realized that I hadn't deleted the php.ini.sample so now when I go into the back end and try to create a configurable product, it gives me that same error from the beginning `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 358555 bytes) in /home/securiteesstore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate/Inline.php on line 207`

Comment: are you on a shared hosting, vps, cloud or what else?

Comment: @AntonioPedicini, it's on a VPS, but apparently has it's separate CPanel areas.